# NHibernate Session.Query<T>().FetchMany

Tags: c#-4.0, nhibernate, lambda, linq-to-nhibernate, queryover

In the following class I want to eager load child collection OrderDetailList using session.Query().FetchMany.

Entity:

```
 public class Order
 {
    public Order()
    {
        OrderDetailList = new HashSet<OrderDetails>();
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; protected internal set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<OrderDetails> OrderDetailList { get;set; }
 }
```

Data Repository:

```
 public IList<T> All()
 {
        IList<T> result;
        using (var _session = _factory.OpenSession())
        {
            result = _session.Query<T>().ToList();
        }
        return result;
}
```

Using the above All method, the child collection returned is proxy object only which result into error as session is closed.
So I want to make the method as:

```
public IList<T> All()
{
        IList<T> result;
        using (var _session = _factory.OpenSession())
        {
            //result = _session.Query<Order>().FetchMany(x=>x.OrderDetailList).ToList();

            //Required Statement: Above statement must be like
            result = _session.Query<T>().FetchMany(x=>x.[Some children property Generic type List in type T]).ToList();

        }
        return result;
}
```

But in this case my method is of generic type hence the property I require to add in FetchMany need to be read from the type T.

How can I achieve this or likewise ?

Comment: Could you make the `x=>x.[Some children property Generic type List in type T]` bit an expression you pass in to the `All()` method?

Comment: The `FetchMany()` method is expecting `Expression<Func<TOriginating, IEnumerable<TRelated>>>`. In this case `TOriginating` would be your `T` and `TRelated` would be whatever types are in `OrderDetailList`.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to need to transmit your fetch as an argument.

```
public IList<T> All<TFetched>(Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TFetched>>> fetchmany)
{
        IList<T> result;
        using (var _session = _factory.OpenSession())
        {
            //result = _session.Query<Order>().FetchMany(x=>x.OrderDetailList).ToList();

            var query = _session.Query<T>();
            if (fetchMany != null)
            {
                query = query.FetchMany(fetchmany);
            }
            result = query.ToList();
        }
        return result;
}
```

Then you could call:

```
orderRepository.All(x=>x.OrderDetailList);
```

This should solve your immediate trouble.

**Notes:**
But please bear in mind that what seems to be your current design is debatable. The session should be short lived, but not to that point. The session should span a unit of work, usually including many data access or writes. By example it may span up to the whole processing of an user triggered event in a desktop application, or the processing of an http request in a web application.

This would then probably enable you to use lazy-loading instead of eager fetching, provided you enable [batch loading](/a/36070727/1178314) of lazy loads for avoiding N+1 loads, and of course provided the entities are no more used after session closing. (This can be achieved by fetching the required data into view-models before closing the session, by example.)

Moreover, you should use explicit transaction. Not doing it creates implicit transactions for each request, which is not good for performances. (But well, with what seems to be your current design, explicit transactions would not change anything currently.) Not using explicit transaction may disable some NHibernate functionalities such as second level cache.